# Recursive function error for traversal of BST

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is my code:

```
class Node:
  def __init__(self,data):
    self.data=data
    self.left=None
    self.right=None
    self.parent=None

class binarytree:
  def __init__(self):
    self.root=None
    self.size=0

   def insert(self,data):
     if self.root==None:
        self.root=Node(data)
     else:
        current=self.root
        while 1:
            if data < current.data:
                if current.left:
                    current=current.left
                else:
                    new=Node(data)
                    current.left=new
                    break;
            elif data > current.data:
                if current.right:
                    current=current.right
                else:
                    new=Node(data)
                    current.right=new
                    break;
            else:
                break

   def print_tree(self):
     current=self.root
     if current.left!=None:
        print_tree(current.left)
     print(current.data)
     if current.right!=None:
        print_tree(current.right)

b=binarytree()
```

When i run the following code and after inserting the elements and when i call the function print_tree i get the error:

```
  File "C:\Windows\System32\btree.py", line 40, in print_tree
    print_tree(current.left)
NameError: name 'print_tree' is not defined
```

Can someone help on this. Thanks in advance

Comment: should be `current.left.print_tree()` not `print_tree(current.left)`

Comment: Or rewrite print_tree as function (rather than as a method) that takes a Node as a parameter.  In any case, the inconsistent indentation or 2, 3, or 4 spaces makes reading harder.  Use an editor such as IDLE that makes consistent indents easy.

Comment: Good heavens, don't save your python files in System32!

Comment: but if i do current.left.print_tree() it will show me the error "AttributeError: 'Node' object has no attribute 'print_tree'"

Comment: There is no global `print_tree` function, only the method `binarytree.print_tree`. You need to redesign your class so that `left` and `right` refer to `binarytree` objects, not `Node` objects.